# Equivalent HMAC SHA512 key of ruby code for Python

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, hmac, hmacsha1

What is the equivalent HMAC SHA512 key of ruby code for the following python code?

**Python**:

```
 import hmac
 import hashlib
 response = hmac.new(PRIVATE_KEY, post_data, hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()
```

I have added a code in ruby as follows. But does not yield the same response as in python

**Ruby**:

```
 require 'digest/hmac'
 response = Digest::HMAC.hexdigest(post_data, PRIVATE_KEY ,Digest::SHA512)
```

url_request_object = urllib2.Request("%s/%s" % (BASE_API_URL,url_suffix),
                                         post_data,
                                         headers)
response = urllib2.urlopen(url_request_object)

**The following is working for me:**

```
   digest = OpenSSL::Digest.new('sha512')

    sign = OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(digest, PRIVATE_KEY, post_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

FYI digest/hmac shouldn't be used. From the Ruby docs

> CAUTION: Use of this library is discouraged, because this implementation was meant to be experimental but somehow got into the 1.9 series without being noticed.

The docs suggest using openssl, but I had better luck with ruby-hmac.  Also, is SHA512 absolutely necessary for you? Here is a solution that works using SHA1.

**Python**:

```
import hmac
import hashlib
response = hmac.new("PRIVATE_KEY", "Stack OverFlow Funtime", hashlib.sha1).hexdigest()
```

gives 203bf02ea1c71df39a1a6b8ad00db836ec89113c

**Ruby**:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'hmac-sha1'

key = 'PRIVATE_KEY'
signature = "Stack OverFlow Funtime"
hmac = HMAC::SHA1.new(key)
hmac.update(signature)
puts "#{hmac.hexdigest}\n"
```

gives 203bf02ea1c71df39a1a6b8ad00db836ec89113c

So using SHA1 and ruby-hmac you can get the same hash in both languages. Hope that helps.